# How to push, or shove, my local workspace to origin/master

Tags: git, github

I started Rebase My Github Fork in Webstorm.  In about a minute I had exactly what I wanted, I was thrilled to finally have something go right with Git.

Now, after an hour of googling, merging, rebasing, creating and switching branches, I feel I’m still no closer to getting git to just accept my changes and push to origin/master.

I would like Git to add two more commands:

```
git just-tell-me-what-the-problem-is

git just-push-what-is-in-my-local-workspace-to-origin-master
```

In the meantime, can someone give me a reliable set of steps to accomplish this?

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/celestially/mantra-sample-blog-app'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: Is `git push` not working? If not, what error are you getting?

Comment: ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/celestially/mantra-sample-blog-app'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: I totally get that git can be confusing... but go on IRC/slack or find a friend that knows it and just ask them. Or take the time to read the hints and try some stuff. Before you can use git, you really need to have some understanding of git and how it works

Answer (score 6):

Well if `git just-tell-me-what-the-problem-is` was added to GIT, it would show the lines that start with "hint:".

Besides **telling the problem** (*"the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart"*), it also shows **the solution**: *"Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again."* and gives you a reference to a place with even **more information**: *"See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details."*